# Move closing </a> tag to the end of a containing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a link to wrap around all text within a div. I can only find solutions where you move certain DOM elements entirely, or move other elements into an element.

current situation:

```
<div class="text">
    <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

desired situation:

```
<div class="text">
    <a href="link">text and more text</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the markup, so I have to do something with jQuery.

Comment: Do you care about the whitespace between the `</a>` and the `</div>`?

Comment: Is it possible to have two `<a>`s in one div? What should happen in that case? I noticed that none of the answers consider multiple siblings and the only suggested fix (`while (this.nextSibling)`) would end up nesting sibling `<a>`s.

Comment: Are you wanting only the text nodes that follow your `</a>` to be added to the `<a>`? What is to happen if there are other elements? Does that change based on what type of element (e.g. do you want to do something different with `<b>` vs. `<div>`)? What if the additional elements have default click actions (e.g. another `<a>`)? Are you wanting to preserve any existing event listeners on, and/or references to, the nodes you move?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the `a` tag is the `firstElementChild` of the `div`? Is your goal to modify the DOM or just to make the entire `div` clickable? And, most importantly, what have you actually tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`.append( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) to insert [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) of anchor into it.

```
$(".text a").append(function(){
  return this.nextSibling
});
```

```js
$(".text a").append(function(){
  return this.nextSibling
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

Also you can use [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) instead and then remove next sibling using [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```
$(".text a").html(function(i, h){
  return h + this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
})[0].nextSibling.remove();
```

Or in **one line** using **ES6**

```
$(".text a").html((i,h) => h+this.nextSibling.nodeValue)[0].nextSibling.remove();
```

```js
$(".text a").html(function(i, h){
  return h + this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
})[0].nextSibling.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

---

Or using **pure javascript**

```
var ele = document.querySelector(".text a");
ele.innerHTML += ele.nextSibling.nodeValue;
ele.nextSibling.remove();
```

```js
var ele = document.querySelector(".text a");
ele.innerHTML += ele.nextSibling.nodeValue;
ele.nextSibling.remove();
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but it's better not to overwrite `innerHTML` .

Comment: Why put that assignment statement in the `return` line when it has nothing to do with the `return`, followed by a comma and then the actual return value? Bad and confusing style, if you ask me.

Comment: @PeterB He is returning `h+text` due to comma operator. But you are right smashing two lines of code into one using comma is not a good style.

Comment: Because you modify `innerHTML` / `.html()` directly, this will disconnect any event listeners that are on the existing content and invalidate any references to the existing content. Doing that could break functionality in the page and/or cause other JavaScript to fail and/or produce exceptions. Unless you *know* that modifying `innerHTML` / `.html()` is acceptable, it's something that should be avoided whenever possible/reasonable.

Answer (score 11):

Avoid messing with html directly, it's better not to change it or overwrite. All you need to do is to take next text sibling Node and append to previous `a`:

```js
$('.text a').each(function() {
  $(this).append(this.nextSibling)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">
  <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

If necessary you can check for the next node to be TextNode, if you need to skip element nodes:

```
if (this.nextSibling.nodeType === 3) {
  $(this).append(this.nextSibling)
}
```

Comment: For completeness, you need a `while(node.nextSibling) ...` loop.

Answer (score 4):

HTML/JavaScript doesn't work in a way that you can "move" a closing tag like that, but what you can do is move the text. Also, you don't need jQuery to do it; it's very easy to do with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.text a')
let textAfterLink = link.nextSibling
link.appendChild(textAfterLink)
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the HTML inside the `div` with class `text` and then replace the closing tag `</a>` with `''` then finally append a closing `</a>` tag to the replaced string so that you get what you expect:

```js
var aHTML = $('.text').html();
aHTML = aHTML.trim().replace(/<\/a>/, '') + '</a>';
$('.text').html(aHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
    <a href="link">text</a> and more text
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one approach that will find all **unwraped** text inside the element with class `.text` and append all of these texts to the first `<a>` child. This approach uses the [content()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method chained with a [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) using the addequated condition for remove the texts children, while at the same time they are appended to the `<a>` element.

```js
$('.text').each(function()
{
    $(this).contents().filter(function()
    {
        // Filter text type only.
        return (this.nodeType === 3);
    })
    .appendTo($(this).find("a:first-child"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">
    <a href="link">text</a> and more text
</div>

<hr>

<div class="text">
  <a href="link">Rise up this morning</a>
  Smile with the rising sun
  <br>
  Three little birds
  <br>
  Pitched by my doorstep
  <br>
  <p>DON'T TOUCH THIS ONE!</p>
  Singing sweet songs
  <br>
  Of melodies pure and true
  <br>
  Sayin': This is my message to you
  <br>
  Saying, don't worry about a thing
  <br>
  'Cause every little thing
  <br>
  Gonna be all right
</div>
```